# Aside или Article

Tags: html5

Что лучше подходит, для элементов просмотра фотографий или видеозаписей. Например, когда в Вконтакте жмешь на видео или фото, то открывается специальный блок для просмотра их, какой тег для этого блока лучше подойдет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте **[здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/html5.)** и **[здесь](http://w3pro.ru/book/spravochnik-html-5/tegi-html-5)**.

Если будете более любопытны и настойчивы в своих поисках, то найдете описание и предназначения практически всех новых элементов **HTML 5**.

Для организации галереи изображений, в большинстве случаев, лучшим выбором будет список (**ul li**), хотя возможны и другие варианты.

Для видео используйте тег **video**, либо iframe, если нужна поддержка старых браузеров.

Удачи

Comment: ну я не про галерею, а про открытие фотографии в белом микро-окошке. Мне кажется aside нужен

Comment: > Мне кажется aside нужен

@Zow, по вашему, "микро-окошко" похоже на сайдбар?